# Advice for implementing functionality in multiple Pickerviews?

Tags: ios, swift

I've hit a bit of a dead-end in XCode and would really appreciate any and all help:

I'm trying to design an app for my dad that will calculate Pressure cooking times for different cuts of meat, based on values I'm going to establish in pickerViews.

Though I've gotten the hang of implementing switch commands to display different Strings of information within four different picker views, corresponding to four meat types (Beef, Pork, Lamb and Poultry) I'm having a lot of trouble with figuring out how to actually get that information to...well, actually act as any kind of meaningful input.

I've been following the example guide from the book "The ultimate ios 10, XCode Guide: Build 30 apps" for a Canadian Tax calculator because, though the end-game isn't the same the functions I was after were featured, and after implementing the four Picker functions like so:

```
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch Beefpicker.tag {
    case 1:
        return listofBeef.count
    case 2:
        return listofPork.count
    case 3:
        return listofLamb.count
    case 4:
        return listofPoultry.count
        
    default:
        break
    }
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch Beefpicker.tag {
    case 1:
        return listofBeef[row]
    case 2:
        return listofPork[row]
    case 3:
        return listofLamb[row]
    case 4:
        return listofPoultry[row]
    
    
    default:
        break
```

It comes to the didSelectRow function, which from what I understand is the actual key to making the values factor in to the overall 'calculation.' But what I'm having trouble with, here, is making it act across all four pickers and not just one. It keeps saying that the code will never be executed, for one thing? Someone on reddit suggested using a tag feature, too, like so:

```
 }
    func pickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,
                    inComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        Beefpicker.tag = 1
        Porkpicker.tag = 2
        Lambpicker.tag = 3
        Poultrypicker.tag = 4
        if Beefpicker.tag = = 1 {}
    }
    }`enter code here`
```

But I'm pretty sure I'm missing something key? Taking out the if statement removes the errors and suggestions to implement a do statement, but consequently makes it so that the two braces above are "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'"

And...well to be honest, I'd just really appreciate if someone could just break this all down and explain what's happening a bit more plainly? As in: What have I done wrong, what has that caused, how should I fix it and *why* should it be that way?

Here's the complete code, including a few variables I've declared as a 'just in case' for later (Long story, but I'm definitely expecting them to be not needed!)

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet weak var KGTextfieldbeef: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var MINSTextfieldBeef: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var KGTextfieldPork:  UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var MINSTextfieldPork: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var KGTextfieldlamb: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var MINSTextfieldlamb: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var KGTextfieldpoulty: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var MINSTextfieldpoultry: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var Beefpicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var Porkpicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var Lambpicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var Poultrypicker: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var btnCalculateButtonbeef: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var  btnCalculateButtonpork: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCalculateButtonlamb: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCalculateButtonpoultry: UIButton!

let Beef = ["Boneless Short Ribs", "Chuck Steak (Cubed)", "Minced Beef (From Frozen)", "Minced Beef", "Burgers (Air-crisp)", "Chuck-Eye Roast", "Beef Brisket", "Steak (Air-Crisp, rare"]

let Pork = ["Bacon (Air-Crisp)", "Sausages (Air-Crisp)", "Boneless Pork Shoulder", "Minced Pork (From Frozen", "Minced Pork", "Pork Tenderloins (Air-crisp)", "Baby Back Pork", "Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp", "Pork Chops (With Bone, Air-Crisp"]

let Lamb = ["Leg of Lamb (Boneless)", "Leg of Lamb", "Lamb Chops (Boneless)", "Lamb Chops", "Lamb Steak", "Minced Lamb"]

let Poultry = ["Chicken Breast (Unfrozen)", "Chicken Breast", "Chicken Thighs", "Chicken Legs", "Chicken Nuggets", "Turkey Breast", "Minced Turkey (Frozen)", "Minced Turkey" ]

var Weight: Double?
var Mins: Double?
var selectedMeat: String?

var listofmeat = ["Minced Beef", "Minced Pork", "Minced Turkey", "Pork Tenderloin", "Sausages (Air-crisp", "Burgers (Air-Crisp)", "Steak (Air-Crisp, rare)", "Chicken Nuggets (Air-Crisp)", "Chicken Breast (Unfrozen", "Chicken Breast (Frozen)", "Chicken Thighs, Bacon (Air-crisp)", "Pork Chops (With Bone", "Air Crisp)","Pork Tenderloins (Air-crisp)", "Baby Back Pork", "Boneless Beef Short Ribs", "Chuck Steak (Cubed)", "Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp)", "Minced Beef (Frozen)", "Minced Pork (Frozen)", "Minced Turkey (Frozen)","Boneless Beef Short Ribs", "Chuck Steak (Cubed)", "Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp)", "Minced Beef (Frozen)", "Minced Pork (Frozen)", "Minced Turkey (Frozen)","Boneless Leg Of Lamb", "Turkey Breast", "Boneless Pork Shoulder", "Beef Brisket"]


var listoffive = ["Minced Beef", "Minced Pork", "Minced Turkey", "Pork Tenderloin,"]

var listoften = ["Sausages (Air-crisp)", "Burgers (Air-Crisp)"," Steak (Air-Crisp, rare)", "Chicken Nuggets (Air-crisp)"]

var listoffifteen = ["Chicken Breast (Unfrozen)", "Chicken Breast (Frozen)", "Chicken Thighs, Bacon (Air-crisp)", "Pork Chops (With Bone", "Air Crisp)"]

var listoftwenty = ["Pork Tenderloins (Air-crisp)", "Baby Back Pork,"]

var listoftwentyfive = ["Boneless Beef Short Ribs", "Chuck Steak (Cubed)", "Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp)", "Minced Beef (Frozen)", "Minced Pork (Frozen)", "Minced Turkey (Frozen)"]

var listofthirty = ["Boneless Leg Of Lamb"]

var listofforty = ["Turkey Breast"]

var listofsixty = ["Beef Chuck-Eye Roast"]

var listofninety = ["Boneless Pork Shoulder", "Beef Brisket"]

var listofBeef: [String] = ["Boneless Short Ribs", "Chuck Steak (Cubed)", "Minced Beef (From Frozen)", "Minced Beef", "Burgers (Air-crisp)", "Chuck-Eye Roast", "Beef Brisket", "Steak (Air-Crisp, rare"]

var listofPork: [String] = ["Bacon (Air-Crisp)", "Sausages (Air-Crisp)", "Boneless Pork Shoulder", "Minced Pork (From Frozen", "Minced Pork", "Pork Tenderloins (Air-crisp)", "Baby Back Pork", "Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp", "Pork Chops (With Bone, Air-Crisp"]

var listofLamb: [String] = ["Leg of Lamb (Boneless)", "Leg of Lamb", "Lamb Chops (Boneless)", "Lamb Chops", "Lamb Steak", "Minced Lamb"]

var listofPoultry: [String] = ["Chicken Breast (Unfrozen)", "Chicken Breast", "Chicken Thighs", "Chicken Legs", "Chicken Nuggets", "Turkey Breast", "Minced Turkey (Frozen)", "Minced Turkey" ]

@IBAction func pressCalculatebuttonbeef(_ sender: UIButton ){}
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch Beefpicker.tag {
    case 1:
        return listofBeef.count
    case 2:
        return listofPork.count
    case 3:
        return listofLamb.count
    case 4:
        return listofPoultry.count
        
    default:
        break
    }
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch Beefpicker.tag {
    case 1:
        return listofBeef[row]
    case 2:
        return listofPork[row]
    case 3:
        return listofLamb[row]
    case 4:
        return listofPoultry[row]
    
    
    default:
        break
        
    
    }
    func pickerView(_pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,
                    inComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        Beefpicker.tag = 1
        Porkpicker.tag = 2
        Lambpicker.tag = 3
        Poultrypicker.tag = 4
      
    }
    }
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
        Beefpicker.delegate = self
        Beefpicker.dataSource = self
        Porkpicker.delegate = self
        Porkpicker.dataSource = self
        Lambpicker.delegate = self
        Lambpicker.dataSource = self
        Poultrypicker.delegate = self
        Poultrypicker.dataSource = self

       
        Beefpicker.tag = 1
        Porkpicker.tag = 2
        Lambpicker.tag = 3
        Poultrypicker.tag = 4
```

}

func CalculateandprintTotal(){

}

}

Comment: You may be able to simplify this a lot - do you really want to display all types of meat at the same time, or do you want to select beef, pork, Lamb, etc, and then choose a cut?  You can have a single picker that shows different data depending on which type of meat you choose

Comment: Either way would work to be honest: I've got them in four separate pickers under four image logo's you see, but I'm definitely open to changing that up via selectable images! I'd really appreciate any and all advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution, now updated to include the weight of meat to be cooked

I have created a simple view with three `UIPickerView` components, named `pickerMeat` (with Tag = 0), `pickerCut` (with Tag = 1) and `pickerWeight` (with Tag = 2) with a display label named `lblInfo`

The easiest way to store the cut of meat & cooking time details is with an array of a user-defined structure.  You can set up a structure something like this

```
struct CookingTimes
{
    var cutOfMeat           : String
    var cookingTimePerKg    : Int

    // because we include _ in the initialiser, we don't have to name the parameters when we use it
    init(_ cutOfMeat : String, _ cookingTimePerKg : Int)
    {
        self.cutOfMeat          = cutOfMeat
        self.cookingTimePerKg   = cookingTimePerKg
    }
}
```

You can use a simple array for the type of meat and an array of CookingTimes

```
let typeOfMeat = ["Beef", "Pork", "Lamb", "Poultry"]
var cutOfMeat = [[CookingTimes]]()
```

you can then define the cut data in `viewDidLoad`.  I have set the times as 10, 11, 12, etc., just so that you can check the selection is right - you will need to update the actual values.

```
    // set up the Beef cuts
    cutOfMeat.append([CookingTimes("Boneless Short Ribs", 10),
                      CookingTimes("Chuck Steak (Cubed)", 11),
                      CookingTimes("Minced Beef (From Frozen)", 12),
                      CookingTimes("Minced Beef", 13),
                      CookingTimes("Burgers (Air-crisp)", 14),
                      CookingTimes("Chuck-Eye Roast", 15),
                      CookingTimes("Beef Brisket", 16),
                      CookingTimes("Steak (Air-Crisp, rare", 17)])
    // set up the Pork
    cutOfMeat.append([CookingTimes("Bacon (Air-Crisp)", 20),
                      CookingTimes("Sausages (Air-Crisp)", 21),
                      CookingTimes("Boneless Pork Shoulder", 22),
                      CookingTimes("Minced Pork (From Frozen", 23),
                      CookingTimes("Minced Pork", 24),
                      CookingTimes("Pork Tenderloins (Air-crisp)", 25),
                      CookingTimes("Baby Back Pork", 26),
                      CookingTimes("Pork Chops (Boneless, Air Crisp", 27),
                      CookingTimes("Pork Chops (With Bone, Air-Crisp",28)])
    // setup the Lamb
    cutOfMeat.append([CookingTimes("Leg of Lamb (Boneless)", 31),
                      CookingTimes("Leg of Lamb", 32),
                      CookingTimes("Lamb Chops (Boneless)", 33),
                      CookingTimes("Lamb Chops", 34),
                      CookingTimes("Lamb Steak", 35),
                      CookingTimes("Minced Lamb",36)])
    // setup the Poultry
    cutOfMeat.append([CookingTimes("Chicken Breast (Unfrozen)", 40),
                    CookingTimes("Chicken Breast", 41),
                    CookingTimes("Chicken Thighs", 42),
                    CookingTimes("Chicken Legs", 43),
                    CookingTimes("Chicken Nuggets", 44),
                    CookingTimes("Turkey Breast", 45),
                    CookingTimes("Minced Turkey (Frozen)", 46),
                    CookingTimes("Minced Turkey",47) ])
```

Then, in your picker view methods, you check if the picker is the type of meat (Tag = 0), the cut (Tag = 1) or the weight (Tag = 2)

```
extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
    {
    // PickerView methods
    // the type of meat picker has tag = 0, the cutOfMeat picker is tag = 1, the weight is tag = 2

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        // this is the same for all pickers, so no check required
        return 1
    }

     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
     {
        //if the type of Meat is selected, change the tracking variable 'typeOfMeatSelected'
        // and refresh the cutofmeat picker
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            // type of meat
            typeOfMeatSelected = row
            pickerCut.reloadAllComponents()
            // select the first entry, otherwise you could have a selected row higher then the current type of meat
            pickerCut.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        case 1:
            // cut of meat
            // display the calculated timings / recipe
            calculateAndPrintTotal()
        case 2:
            // weight of meat
            weightSelected = weightOfMeat[row]
            // display the calculated timings / recipe
            calculateAndPrintTotal()
        default:
            print("Something is missing if we see this")
        }
     }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
    switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            return typeOfMeat.count

        case 1:
            return cutOfMeat[typeOfMeatSelected].count
    
        case 2:
            return weightOfMeat.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        switch pickerView.tag {
        case 0:
            return typeOfMeat[row]

        case 1:
            return cutOfMeat[typeOfMeatSelected][row].cutOfMeat
    
        case 2:
            return ("\(weightOfMeat[row]) Kg")
        default:
            return "unknown"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I updated the `UILabel` with info to show that you had made the selection - and a simple calculation of the cooking time

```
func calculateAndPrintTotal()
{
    // display timings / recipe based on selection
    // simple assumption that cooking time is time per Kg x weight
    // in practise, the time per Kg may reduce for larger weights,
    // but you could add that in the struct CookingTimeswith something like timePerKG_Under3Kg, timePerKG_Over3Kg
    let meat    = typeOfMeat[typeOfMeatSelected]
    let cut     = cutOfMeat[typeOfMeatSelected][pickerCut.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)].cutOfMeat
    
    let cookingTime = weightSelected * Double(cutOfMeat[typeOfMeatSelected][pickerCut.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)].cookingTimePerKg)

    
    lblInfo.text = "Show details for \(meat), \(cut), \(weightSelected) Kg \n\n Cooking time is \(cookingTime) minutes"

}
```

Comment: Wow, thankyou! This is incredibly helpful and insightful! So, going by this: now that the pickerviews are set up, where would I start setting up for implementing these values into the calculation? So far I've declared functions with switch statements like: case "Boneless Pork Shoulder", "Beef Brisket" Mins = 90, and ditto for the Weight, only those values = 1--I'm guessing that might not get me very far though, given that 90 * 1 is still just going to be 1? (Again, thankyou so much for this, I really appreciate it!)

Comment: Also, just wanted to apologise if I'm misunderstanding anything: I'm autistic and sometimes I just need a bit extra context before things 'click', haha... But again, really appreciate this!!

Comment: @Batgirl - happy to help.  I get a lot of out of this as well :-)  If you like the answer, please go ahead and accept it.
I will update the answer to show one way of showing the cooking times, that will be a lot simpler than what you're suggesting...

Comment: Don't worry, I will! But just to be clear: This will also allow me to change the value of the meat weight when it comes to calculating? Like it'll allow for changing user-inputted values 1KG, 2KG, ect and let me set the up calculation that way? Or would I need a totally different code altogether...?

Comment: I will add a picker for weight, and you will be sorted :-)

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question though, my XCode doesn't seem to accept the .append command? It can't find it in the scope?I take things ungodly literally to a fault, so I'm assuming I'm not just trying to copy and paste things here (as is right, I need to learn for myself!) It's also not recognising its' own view controller but...I have no idea if that's just the file throwing a tantrum, because that's happened a few times now and righted itself...

Comment: odd - I think you've probably missed something unrelated that's knocking out the parsing of the file.  
I've loaded my test files to GitHub - you can have a look at the complete project there to see how it all hangs together

https://github.com/CarterMiller/PickerViewTest

Comment: Aw thankyou so much, that is incredibly helpful!! Seriously, I can't tell you how grateful I am for your time and efforts!